# Opencart 3 show content based on product category

Tags: twig, opencart

I'd like to show content based on whether or not a product is in a certain category. For example, I have categories "Custom Portraits" and "Printed on Things"

So I'd like something like

---

If product category == "Custom Portraits"

then "content"

else if product category == "Printed on Things"

then "different content"

else

then no content

endif

---

What's the right twig syntax in OpenCart 3 for something like that?

Comment: A solution would be to modify the category entity with an extra field "template" and the just do , `{% for product in products %}{% include product.getCategory().getContentTemplate() ignore missing %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.